# How to read/set Excel Textbox property from MS-Access VBA

Tags: excel, vba, textbox, excel-2016, ms-access-2016

I have a simple Textbox in Excel worksheet (.xlsx) where I can read the BackColor property in Excel VBA sub with:

```
Debug.Print TextBox1.BackColor
```

I'm trying to reference that same textbox from MS-Access using the Excel 16 Object Model, but it can't see the textbox under any of the Excel Worksheet objects I'm looking at

It errors out on the line marked with asterisks below with error message

> Method or Data Member Not Found

```
Public Sub SetHexColor()

    Dim xlApp   As Excel.Application
    Dim xlBook  As Excel.Workbook
    Dim xlSheet As Excel.Worksheet
    
    Set xlApp = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
    
    Set xlBook = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\.........\Documents\TextBox.xlsx")
    Set xlSheet = xlBook.Worksheets(1)
    **Debug.Print xlSheet.TextBox1.BackColor**
    
    Set xlSheet = Nothing
    Set xlBook = Nothing
    Set xlApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

Is there another way to reference and preferably set properties of a Textbox control in Excel?

I'd prefer not to have call an Excel function to set the property if possible - or maybe that's the issue - it has to be an xlsm file?

Comment: Try `Dim xlSheet As Object`   The type `Excel.Worksheet` doesn't have a built-in `TextBox1` member

Comment: What? How does that work! The object model is different from preload to postload? Thanks so much. Add that to an answer and I'll mark it. I had no idea

Comment: Or you can leave it as `As Worksheet` and use something like  `xlSheet.OLEObjects("TextBox1")` to reference the control.   `Excel.Worksheet` is a generic worksheet object - it only provides access to "out of the box" methods of the Worksheet object: if you've "subclassed" your worksheet by adding members such as `TextBox1` then you can't access those members via the generic type.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I tried the OLEObjects property

Comment: You need to tag on `.Object` before you can work with it, so `xlSheet.OLEObjects("TextBox1").Object.BackColor` for example

Comment: Okay - excellent - I'll play with this Automation tonight. Thanks again. If you add both options to your answer that'll be perfect reference for later

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Excel.Worksheet` is a generic worksheet object - it only provides access to "out of the box" methods of the `Worksheet` object: if you've "subclassed" your worksheet by adding members such as `TextBox1` then you can't access those added members via the generic `Worksheet` type.

You can either do this

```
Dim xlSheet As Object
```

or leave the declaration as-is, and use something like

```
Debug.Print xlSheet.OLEObjects("TextBox1").Object.BackColor
```

Note this is not specific to automating Excel from access VBA - the same would be true if working entirely within Excel.